# Что можно писать в комментариях?

Tags: обсуждение

Кажется, в комментариях можно уточнять информацию по ответу. Если вы полностью не согласны с ответом, то надо дать свой альтернативный вариант.

**Но не все так думают.**

Некоторые считают, в комментариях уместна разговорная речь, грубые фразеологизмы, необоснованные оценки сказанного, причем всё это **без своего правильного и обоснованного ответа** с приведением необходимых ссылок.

И конечно, никак не обойтись **без минусовки уже данного ответа** (а он-то как раз  был дан  с ссылками и подробным анализом заданного вопроса).

И если своего ответа нет, то **как можно назвать такой комментарий?**

**Это нормально? Комментарии именно для этого предназначены?**

Я считаю, что такое поведение должно получить оценку сообщества. **Разве можно вообще работать на форуме, если в любой момент твой труд обесценивают подобные участники?**

Это вопрос:

[Вы лучше(,) чем кто-либо(,) знаете, какой вред этот продукт может нанести организму](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450303/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-)
органи/450306?noredirect=1#comment461123_450306

В нем автор говорит **о наличии вариантов,** поэтому я их объясняю.

А это комментарий:

Прии чем здесь "более чем"? **Наводите тень на плетень, когда вопрос выеденного яйца не стоит..**. Как там пишут в подобных случаях наши модераторы? – "Не является ответом на вопрос"? Вот здесь это прямо в точку. **Разумеется, обособление необходимо,** отсутствие – грубая ошибка, за которую школьникам не четверку, а сразу **трояк** надо ставить. – Niemand

"Разумеется, обособление необходимо" — **это и есть всё "обоснование".**

И еще: **"вопрос выеденного яйца не стоит".** Это как надо понимать? Так выражено отношение участника к автору вопроса? **Такое поведение подрывает авторитет всего сообщества.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, помейчайте тревогой комментарии, нарушающие правила. Об остальном -- см. по ссылке выше.

Comment: Нет, это отношение к автору ответа. Это надо понимать так, что обороты типа "лучше, чем кто-либо" обособляются всегда. Вот всегда! Вы же произвольно изменили оборот, весь свой ответ посвятили этому измененному и в самом конце походя добавили, что все, что вы сказали, якобы *должно* относиться и к исходному обороту. Ну и кто здесь дед-мороз? Не смешивайте ваш авторитет с "авторитетом всего сообщества".